# Using previously defined function in ColorFunction

Tags: plotting, functions, color

I want to use a previously defined function as part of a function definition for `ColorFunction`. I tried the following and it worked:

```
f = x;
Plot[Cos[x], {x, 0, Pi}, ColorFunction -> Function[Evaluate@f, Hue[x]]]
```

[image]

However if I slightly tweak the function it stops working. So my guess is that my approach is wrong from the beginning. How should I be approaching this?

```
f = 1.0001 x;
Plot[Cos[x], {x, 0, Pi}, ColorFunction -> Function[Evaluate@f, Hue[x]]]
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
f = 1.0001 x;
Plot[Cos[x], {x, 0, Pi}, ColorFunction -> Function[x, Hue[f]]]
```

[image]

Comment: Ah yes, I think I just made a mistake. I should specify the variable first and then give the function inside Hue. This is what I was looking for.

Answer (score 3):

Use `SetDelayed` to define `f` and give it an argument.

```
f[x_] := Hue[x]
Plot[Cos[x], {x, 0, Pi}, ColorFunction -> f]
```

[image: plot_a]

Then, should you tweak `f` you don't have make any change to the `Plot` expression.

```
f[x_] := Hue[Cos[x]]
Plot[Cos[x], {x, 0, Pi}, ColorFunction -> f]
```

[image: plot_b]

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
f[x_] := Hue[x]
Plot[Cos[x], {x, 0, Pi}, ColorFunction -> (Function[{x}, f[x] ] )]
```

[image]